# AchartEngine Time Chart duplicated X labels

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine library for Android to create a time chart.
I wonder if is there any way I can limit the zoom so that the X labels do not appear duplicated as in the image?

[image: Screen 1]

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to fix this. For instance, you can change the date format of the time chart you are displaying.

Comment: Can you explain with an example? Thanks

Comment: Show me your code. I cannot guess what you do just from a screenshot.

Comment: Apparently renderer.setXRoundedLabels(false) resolved this issue

Comment: `setXRoundedLabels(false)` did it for me as well, which is odd because that is the opposite of what I would expect it to do. I would expect that setting it to true would round the labels to the nearest "bucket", not add more "buckets."